# Issues with density plots in R using geom_density_2d_filled

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, density-plot

I have **x** and **y** positions and I want to draw a density map using ggplot however, it gives me the following error:

> Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative
> integer In addition: Warning messages: 1: Computation failed in
> `stat_density2d_filled()`: bandwidths must be strictly positive  2: In
> min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :   no non-missing arguments to min; returning
> Inf 3: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :   no non-missing arguments to max;
> returning -Inf 4: In max(f) : no non-missing arguments to max;
> returning -Inf

Both **x** and **y** are numeric and there are no missing values. But I still keep getting the same error. The code I am using is:

```
  ggplot(Fish, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos)) + 
geom_density_2d_filled(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=0.85, breaks= c(0,10^-5, 10^-4,10^-3,10^-2,10^-1,1),
                       contour_var = "ndensity") +
scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq",palette = "Spectral", direction = -1)
```

This code works fine for other data sets where I have **x** and **y** positions for other fishes. But this data set is giving errors.

The link to the CSV file with data is: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNjFHT7afKVdnp9xvdQ4lpQg-QxOCyOP/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Based on your description this is likely something in your data, not your code, so without a sample of your data it will be difficult to assist.

Comment: I did not know how to provide data here but I have added a link to download the .csv file with data.

Comment: if possible, please use `dput(yourdata)` and paste the output instead of providing a  link. This will ensure we have the exact structure to recreate your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is problem with your data, not the code. There is a disproportionate number of `ypos` values at `ypos = 30` (~82%) and also a `ypos==0`. This is complicating the ability it to calculate the density (likely producing an `NaN` or `Inf` as `seq_length()` expects a number).

The code you pasted does work if you remove this issue, so I would suggest you scrutinize the data, or code that led to the data, instead of this code itself.

```
Fish <- read.csv(".../fish.csv")

NewFish <- Fish[Fish$ypos>0 & Fish$ypos<30,]

ggplot(Fish, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos)) + 
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=0.85, breaks= c(0,10^-5, 10^-4,10^-3,10^-2,10^-1,1),
                         contour_var = "ndensity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq",palette = "Spectral", direction = -1)
```

[image]